# Accessing same variables in different python scripts preserving values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below scripts

script1:

```
var1 = 10
var2 = []
```

script2:

```
import script1
script1.var1 = script1.var1 + 10
script1.var2 = script1.var2.append['1']
```

script3:

```
import script1 
script1.var1 = script1.var1 + 10
script1.var2 = script1.var2.append['2']
print script1.var1
print script1.var2
```

script2 will execute first then script3

In script3,  script1 is importing so all values update as per script 1

I am expecting var1 to print 30 and var2  print ['1', '2']

So what is the best way to use variables in this case.

Comment: `So what is the best way to use variables in this case.` What does that even mean? I don't get your question. What is the problem? Can't you just import `script2` in `script3`?

Comment: Are those ran independently of each other, i.e. `python script2.py; python script3.py`, or are those modules part of a single program?

Comment: i must import script1 in script3

Answer (score 2):

As I understand the question, `script2` and `script3` are ran independently of each other, i.e.

```
$ python script2.py
$ python script3.py
```

Then, no, changes you make to variables of `script1` in `script2` will not be persisted after the program has finished. However, if you have another script, call it `script4.py`, that executes both of`script2` and `script3` within the same program...

```
import script2
import script3
```

... then the changes will be persisted (im memory) and `script3` should print `30` and `['1', '2']` as you expected.

If you want to store variables between program execution, I suggest you have a look at [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html), or some other [persistence module for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html), for storing data on disk or in a data base.

Comment: What I would actually suggest is not json (which is just a format, it doesn't really matter) but rather ways to persist data, e.g. file system or perhaps some database like sqlite.

Comment: @freakish That's why I liked to the `json` module, not to some page describing the format. Of course, you can also use `pickle` or just write to a plain text file, but IMHO `json` is easiest to use.

Comment: Yeah, but using json won't make your code automagically persistent. It is unrelated to that at all. The format might be helpful but at the end of the day what really matters is the file system or some external database.